# Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor-even i have used first statement

Tags: java, constructor, this

What's wrong in below code?
Why am I unable to call `this()` method when it's the first statement?

```java
package oopsConcepts;

public class Testing {
    int age;
    int salary;
    int amount;
    private int marks;

    public Testing Testing(int age, int salary, int amount) {
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.amount = amount;
        marks = 200;
        return this;
    }

    public int Testing(int age, int salary) {
        // this(23,9999,140);
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
        return 50;
    }

    public Testing Testing() {
        this(23, 9999);
        // System.out.println("Hey dude default constructor");
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Testing t1 = new Testing();
        t1.Testing().Testing(32, 45678);
        System.out.println(t1.age);
        System.out.println(t1.salary);
        System.out.println(t1.amount);
        System.out.println(t1.marks);
    }
}
```

Please resolve error in the above code.
To know how to call `this()` if the constructor has return type of only this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iYz7.jpg)

Comment: I wonder what are the warnings at lines 10, 18, and 26 ... (at least that icon on the left of the line number seems like some kind of warning)

Answer (score 1):

Constructors don't have return types.  You *must* write them like `public Testing() {...}`, not `public Testing Testing(){...}` or `public int Testing() {...}`, and you *must not* return any values from them, like `return 50;` or even `return this;`.

If you write them properly as constructors, you will be able to use the `this(...)` syntax.

As it is, you are defining methods in the class `Testing` that just happen to also be named `Testing`, and you cannot call `this(...)` as a constructor helper from a normal method.

Comment: return this will be allowed and its working for me

Comment: From a correctly written constructor?  I'd be surprised.  If `return this` works at all, then that indicates you're not actually in a constructor, you're in a method.

Comment: @RaviTeja Your code does not define _any_ explicit constructors for `Testing`, which means a default no-argument constructor is implicitly defined by the compiler. Every one of your `Testing(...)` "constructors" are actually _methods_ that happen to have the same name as the class. The return types make them methods.